# How to alternate the web controller response between HttpEntity and ModelAndView in Spring

Tags: java, spring

I have a Spring 3.0 application, with an Web Controller Method. This method normaly return a file in the http response, therefore I used the return type `org.springframework.http.HttpEntity`. But now there is a second requirement: if the file is larger than 1MB and it is after 10 o'clock, a HTML page should be displayed.

So my problem is, that the method sometimes should be return a `HttpEntity<byte[]>` and sometimes a `ModelAndView`. But how can one have this two different kinds of a return type?

(*Ok the requirement is not 10 o'clock, it is much more complicated, but the point is, that this dessicion can be made only in the controller.*)

(This application uses classic JSPX for rendering HTML paged.)

Comment: A redirect? You then have two entry points, two requests.

Comment: @Joop Eggen: good idea, maybe a forward, then I do not have two requests.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Its too easy (sorry for the question): one could define the method with return type `Object`, so one could return instances of `ModelAndView` or `HttpEntity`.

This works because the `AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter#getModelAndView` takes the return value as an `Object` and then has a if-then-else cascade with an lot of `inncstanceof` statements to determine the concreate instance type.

---

If one feels that the return type `Object` is too common, then one could define its own class (compound-class), witch contains a `ModelAndView` or `HttpEntity` in two different fields. And then one have to write a custom `ModelAndViewResolver`.

This custom `ModelAndViewResolver` take the compound-object and

- return a model and view if it is the compound-class for `ModelAndView`  or
- updates the `webRequest` like `AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter#handleHttpEntityResponse` does and then returns null

Comment: +1, @Ralph. I thought about returning Object but was not sure. Good to know.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the better solution here is using regular HTTP filter that checks the conditions and either forwards the request to "normal" flow or to HTML page.

This allows you to decouple your logic. Probably in future you will receive yet another requirement that forwards request to yet another path. You can implement this in yet another filter.

The filters can use the same Spring context and therefore use the same beans, DB etc.

EDIT. Think about Spring interceptor too. I personally have not used this technique but it can help here also.